# How to generate an array of integers for use in a UIPickerView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4, nsmutablearray

I'm using a UIPickerView and I want to load in a range of numbers to be displayed by the picker so I figured I'd use an NSMutableArray. I have two components in the picker view so I want to generate two different array's. I am generating my first array like this,

```
    NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:401];
    for (int i=420; i>=20; i--) {
        [array1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
    }

    self.myArray1 = array1;
```

This is working fine **HOWEVER** when I try generating my second array my app is crashing with no output to the console. The second array is being generated like this,

```
NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:11];
for (int j=0; j<=10; j--) {
    [array2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", j]];
}

self.myArray2 = array2;
```

What could I be doing wrong??

**UPDATE:**
Just want to add that I've tried creating these array's in both the init method of my class and the view didLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j--` should be `j++` as you are looping j from 0 to 10.

Comment: @cgossian, one should believe in one self :-)